# Why does the w3schools JavaScript cookies example not work with html Documents?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

This is a rehash of another question that I asked, because it hasn't received any replies yet and I fell I could simplify the question.

The cookies example on http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp works in the w3schools "Try it yourself" window, but not on raw HTML documents.

Here is what I do: I copy and paste the code from the example into a notepad document, I save the document as an HTML document and then open it with Google Chrome. The website asks for me to input my name (good so far) but then doesn't give me a greeting message when I refresh the page! The cookie doesn't seem to save.

Why does the example work on the website but not with my method? How can I fix this?

Comment: I bet Chrome won't let documents loaded via `file://` URLs set/read cookies. Try serving the content via HTTP.

Comment: Also many examples at w3schools are substandard. This particular example seems ok, but it is not a resource I recommend. MDN is better and there are many other sites such as http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html that are of higher quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your HTML document over HTTP. Opening it from your hard disk doesn't give your browser a sensible URL to associate the cookie with.

You can install a webserver (such as Apache) and access the document via `http://localhost`.

Comment: Ah ok, so I need to set up a Webserver on my home computer? And I can just Google how to do that?1

Comment: You need to do your testing through a webserver. It doesn't necessarily have to be installed on the machine you do the development on, although it is quite common to do so (or to run a VM with a Linux install on it for that purpose). There are plenty of web servers out there, I suggested one, Google will help you find others. They tend to come with documentation.